# Detecting 429 and 418 return codes in HttpResponseMessage

Tags: c#, httpclient, rest

I am consuming a WebAPI. The specification under https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#general-api-information defines the following rules for Http response codes:

**HTTP Return Codes**

```
HTTP 4XX return codes are used for malformed requests; the issue is on the sender's side.

HTTP 403 return code is used when the WAF Limit (Web Application Firewall) has been violated.

HTTP 429 return code is used when breaking a request rate limit.

HTTP 418 return code is used when an IP has been auto-banned for continuing to send requests after receiving 429 codes.

HTTP 5XX return codes are used for internal errors; the issue is on Binance's side.

With using /wapi/v3 [something fancy]
```

So it is particularly important for me to detect 429 and 418 return codes.

I am consuming the WebApi like this:

```
httpResponse = await _httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequest, cancellationToken)
    .ConfigureAwait(false);

if (httpResponse.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TResponse>(
        await httpResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
}
else
{
    switch (httpResponse.StatusCode)
    {
        case (HttpStatusCode.Forbidden):
            throw new BinanceWafLimitViolation();

        // ... More Status Codes here ...

        default:
            throw new RestApiException("Http status code indicates failure");
    }
}
```

but I am puzzled as on how to detect the return codes in question as they are not defined in `HttpStatusCode`. Let alone how to determine whether the status code is in the 4XX or 5XX range.

I am using dotnetcore3.1 which is important, since I cannot just get the status code by calling `httpResponse.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` and extracting it from the Exception.

Comment: What is the question? How to compare a `StatusCode` to an `int`?

Comment: Please look up casting enums to integers.

Comment: case (HttpStatusCode)418: or just use an int

Comment: 429 == [TooManyRequests](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=netcore-3.1#System_Net_HttpStatusCode_TooManyRequests) - the other one you would need to cast to int and compare with that

Comment: But if there is no value defined for HttpStatusCode 418. If the value is not defined, then it can never be assigned by the framework and hence the comparison to the enum value will always fail. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Benj The values defined by that enum are merely a list of **well-known** status codes that most HTTP clients and servers understand. There's nothing preventing anyone from creating their own specific status code, and indeed the HTTP specification explicitly allows this for extensibility. Similarly, .NET enums are not exhaustive lists to cater for the same scenario - it's perfectly valid to write `var statusCode = (HttpStatusCode)999`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to assign any arbitrary integer value to an `enum` type, so to use it in a `switch` it's as simple as *cast*

```
switch (httpResponse.StatusCode)
{
   case HttpStatusCode.Forbidden:
    ...
   case HttpStatusCode.TooManyRequests:
    ...
   case (HttpStatusCode)418:
    ...

}
```

[From the specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/enums#enum-values-and-operations)

> **Enum values and operations**
>
> Each enum type defines a distinct type; an explicit enumeration
> conversion (Explicit enumeration conversions) is required to convert
> between an enum type and an integral type, or between two enum types.
> **The set of values that an enum type can take on is not limited by its enum members. In particular, any value of the underlying type of
> an enum can be cast to the enum type, and is a distinct valid value of
> that enum type**.

Or as suggested by [@Dominik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6870620/dominik) further information at [Enum Type Conversions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#conversions)

Comment: Might wanna throw https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/enum#conversions in there. A nice example that shows eactly what the OP will/should do.

Comment: @Dominik +1 for referring to the german specification. very convenient ;-)

Comment: @Benj Woops, sorry. I can't change it anymore though.

Comment: @Dominik passt schon